# Call to undefined method PDOStatement::query()

Tags: php, pdo

I am learning PDO and I am facing an issue which I do not have a clue about. So, I have a category table (Guitar, Drums etc) and another product table (having product of each type of categories). I am learning MVC and I am trying to list all the products for a particular category.

This is what I have for my controller which is still incomplete:

```
<?php
include './model/database.php';
include './model/category.php';
include './model/product.php';
// What is the default action
if(isset($_POST['action'])){  
    $action=$_POST['action'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action=$_GET['action'];  
}
else {
    $action='product_list'; // Default Action 
}
if($action==='product_list'){
    if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
            $category_id=$_GET('category_id');
} else {
    $category_id=1;
       }
}
$category_name=get_category_name($category_id);
$catagories=get_categories();
$products= get_product_by_category($category_id);
include('product_display.php');

?>
```

This is my categories.php file:

```
<?php
    function get_categories(){
        global $db;
        $query="SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categoryID";
        $categories=$db->query($query); //line 5
        return $categories;
    }
    function get_category_name($category_id){
        global $db;
        $query="SELECT categoryName FROM categories
                WHERE categoryID=$category_id";
        $db=$db->query($query);
        $category=$db->fetch();
        $category_name=$category['categoryName'];
        return $category_name;
    }
?>
```

This is my database.php file :

```
<?php 
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_guitar_shop1';
$user='mgs_user';
$password='pa55word';
try {
   $db= new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $error_message=$ex->getMessage();
    include 'database_error.php';
    exit();   
}
?>
```

It gives me an error:

> Call to undefined method PDOStatement::query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mvcfirst\model\category.php on line 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why the consensus is that [globals are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). In your `database.php` file you're setting the `$db` variable to a `PDO` object:

```
$db= new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

And then in your categories.php file you overwrite the `$db` variable with a `PDOStatement` object:

```
$db=$db->query($query);
```

`PDO::query()` returns a `PDOStatement` object, which does not have a `query()` method. Thus the error you're getting.

On another note, you need to be using prepared statements with bound parameters or else your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can also use `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` to select a single column:

```
function get_category_name($category_id){
    global $db; // Yuck!
    $query="SELECT categoryName FROM categories
            WHERE categoryID = ?";
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([$category_id]);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: I could not quite understand what you mean .

Comment: Got it now . Thanks a lot Mike you made me a happy man :) . I will look into the SQL injection bit later . I am kindda overwhelmed with so many things to learn and remember .

Comment: Glad I could help!